# Send invoice via email after generate invoice opencart

Tags: email, opencart, invoice

I'm facing problem for get the complete invoice email after generate the invoice from admin sale->order.

How can send complete invoice via email after generate invoice from opencart 2.1 admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can check following chrome extension to create quick invoice.
[here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hyperbook-invoice/knnjcpbhgjohohiofdcgbbmldlcjploc)